# Swap file is not recognized by the Ubuntu server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, configuration, swap

I've noticed that my Ubuntu server is using smaller swap file then there is available.
swapon shows 9GB swap file, but other commands show 1GB swap file

Some outputs:

swapon --show

```
NAME TYPE    SIZE    USED PRIO
none virtual   9G 1019.5M    0
```

top

```
MiB Mem :   8192.0 total,    680.8 free,   2137.4 used,   5373.9 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   1024.0 total,     66.7 free,    957.3 used.   6054.6 avail Mem
```

free -h

```
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           8.0Gi       2.1Gi       546Mi       1.6Gi       5.4Gi       5.9Gi
Swap:          1.0Gi       967Mi        57Mi
```

/etc/fstab

```
# UNCONFIGURED FSTAB FOR BASE SYSTEM
```

I'm not an expert in linux servers, but what I see is that swap file is being heavily utilised and at the same time it is limited by 1GB, while there is actually 9GB file available.
Please explain how can I enable 9GB swap file

Answer (score 1):

You probably can find out better where the OS has it swapfile mapped by executing `cat /proc/swaps` before doing anything "in the blind".

Anyway, to create a new swapfile is follow this steps:

1. Create a 9G swapfile: `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1024 count=9437184`
2. Change swapfile permissions: `chmod 600 /swapfile`
3. Create swap filesystem: `mkswap /swapfile`
4. Unmount the old swap: `sudo swapoff -a`
5. Mount the new swap: `sudo swapon /swapfile`
6. Check swap is working `free -m` or `swapon --show`
7. Add an entry to */etc/fstab* like this: `/swapfile swap swap defaults 0 0`

Comment: executed this steps, added 9GB file, swapon shows same none virtual 9G, other commands show 1GB swap file, nothing changed. Btw when I ran sudo swapoff -a, I checked if I no longer have a swap file, but I still had this 1GB. I cant understand why server uses 1GB swap file if it is not specified anywhere.